# Toyota Ractis 1.5 cvt

Tags: electrical, toyota

Good evening guys, I don't speak English very well, so I will try my best:
sometimes (this happens especially when I turn the AC on), the engine start shaking and the dashboard lights start oscillating. After and couple of minutes, the AC, radio and dashboard lights power off but the engine remains on.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Does the car startup just fine? Your description makes me wonder if there isn't a problem with the battery or charging system.

Comment: Thank you paulster.. yes sir, the car start just fine .. even when this happens the car keeps working fine ..

Comment: I suggest you to submit a separate question about the downshift paddle and edit your post to remove the downshift paddle question from the AC question. It is generally the case in this site that one question should contain just one question and not several ones. You should obviously provide more details to the new question about the downshift paddle problem: is there an upshift paddle? Does it work?

Comment: thanks juhist, post edited as you suggested.. yes there is a upshift paddle and it works perfectly.. my issue is only with the downshift.